# Insert Character at Descending Index Positions within Nested List

Tags: python, list

I need a way of appending or inserting a `/` in descending index positions for each row in a matrix-like structure.  What I have going on is I have a program that takes in a starting value of the list and the length^2 then creates the list from those values I.E.:

```
answer(17, 4) = [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]
```

Then I turn it into a matrix or nested list with:

```
matrix = [id_arr[i:i + length] for i in range(0, len(id_arr), length)]
```

Output: `[[17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27, 28], [29, 30, 31, 32]]`

```
[17, 18, 19, 20]  # matrix[0]
[21, 22, 23, 24]  # matrix[1]
[25, 26, 27, 28]  # matrix[2]
[29, 30, 31, 32]  # matrix[3]
```

Now I want a way to insert or append the `/` at decreasing index positions for each row of the matrix I.E:

```
17 18 19 20 /
21 22 23 / 24
25 26 / 27 28
29 / 30 31 32
```

Full Code:

```
def answer(start, length):
    # Generate the list of given start value and length
    id_arr = list(range(start, start + length ** 2))

    # Create a matrix of the list
    matrix = [id_arr[i:i + length] for i in range(0, len(id_arr), length)]

    # Attempt to try and insert the /
    for row in matrix:
        row.insert(len(matrix), '/')
        print row
    print len(matrix)

answer(17, 4)
```

Output:

```
[17, 18, 19, 20, '/']
[21, 22, 23, 24, '/']
[25, 26, 27, 28, '/']
[29, 30, 31, 32, '/']
```

As you can see my current code only appends the `/` at the end of each row.

Comment: you have to insert `/` during the create matrix process..

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan Somewhere in the `matrix = ` list comprehension?

Answer (score 3):

use enumerate and get the index of the each row and inssert / every length of row minus the index

```
 def answer(start, length):
    # Generate the list of given start value and length
    id_arr = list(range(start, start + length ** 2))

    # Create a matrix of the list
    matrix = [id_arr[i:i + length] for i in range(0, len(id_arr), length)]

    # Attempt to try and insert the /
    for i,row in enumerate(matrix):
        row.insert(len(matrix)-i, '/')
        print row
    print len(matrix)

 answer(17, 4)
```

output :

```
[17, 18, 19, 20, '/']
[21, 22, 23, '/', 24]
[25, 26, '/', 27, 28]
[29, '/', 30, 31, 32]
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just decrement the index at which you insert the `/`

```
def answer(start, length):
    # Generate the list of given start value and length
    id_arr = list(range(start, start + length ** 2))

    # Create a matrix of the list
    matrix = [id_arr[i:i + length] for i in range(0, len(id_arr), length)]

    # Attempt to try and insert the /
    l = len(matrix)
    for row in matrix:
        row.insert(l, '/')
        l -= 1
        print row
    print len(matrix)

answer(17, 4)
```